# Get substring based on matching string

Tags: string, excel, excel-2007

I am using Excel 2007. In column B I have quite long strings that contain some pattern string like:

`Amazon: 'Multicoloured'`  or
 `Amazon: 'White'` or
 `SKU 7701371034719, ASIN B00E4ZQSYE, ('color' Merchant: 'Sheer Black' / Amazon: 'Black Sheer')`

or more in different rows of the same column.

If any row of column B contains this type of matching string, I want to get the color value from this matching string in the next column of the same row.

How can we do this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data starts in B1, please try:

```
=MID(B1,FIND("Amazon",B1)+8,FIND(" ",MID(B1,FIND("Amazon",B1)+8,20)))
```

in C1 and copy down to suit.

For colours of multiple words (*or* single) please instead try:

```
=MID(B1,FIND("Amazon",B1)+8,FIND("'",B1,FIND("Amazon",B1)+9)-FIND("Amazon",B1)-7)
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply. According to your solution it gives right output but not that i want. For example i have a string like "SKU 7701371034719, ASIN B00E4ZQSYE, ('color' Merchant: 'Sheer Black' / Amazon: 'Black Sheer').If your product is the same as this ASIN, please modify your product data to reflect the following Amazon catalog values and resubmit.
". Your solution gives me "'Black" but i want "Black Sheer" from string. Please reply me.